# MySQL trigger behaviour with failed transactions

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have found a fair bit of information on what happens when a trigger fails, but have not been able to find any on what happens when the transaction fails.

Let's assume I have two tables, table A and table B.  I have defined a BEFORE INSERT trigger such that an insert on table A will cause the trigger to update table B.  I understand that if the trigger fails, the insert transaction will not be executed.  What happens when the trigger executes successfully and then the insert fails?  Will the update on table B be rolled back?

Taking this a step further, let's say I have also defined table C and a BEFORE UPDATE trigger such that an update on table B will cause the trigger to update table C.  The intended behaviour when all works well is such that when a row is inserted into table A, a trigger will update table B which will cause another trigger to update table C.  Since both are BEFORE triggers, these operations would be executed in reverse, as in table C will be updated first, then B, then the insert will be performed on A.  What happens when the insert on A fails?  Will the updates on both B and C be rolled back?

Comment: If all your tables are using an ACID-compliant storage engine (such as InnoDB) *and* you `ROLLBACK` the transaction when so desired, then any modifications made by a trigger (or other stored program) will also be rolled back.

Comment: Thank you.  I have also realized that AFTER timer for the event would be more appropriate in the case where I'm updating values in another table, in which case the triggers wouldn't have had a chance to execute until after the parent transaction has successfully completed.